# How to prevent enabling inspect element by blocking script on browser

Tags: javascript, inspect

I have blocked the right-click on my webpage but users can view "inspect element" by blocking the script on a web browser. Once we block the script from a web browser, it enables the right-click. Is there any solution to prevent this issue? Thanks

[I have added an image of blocking script from web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib5f8.png)

Comment: No, there is no way to prevent users from inspecting element. What's the purpose of doing this ?

Comment: If you're worried about client logic, you should move it server side

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me and idea about this 辛忠柱 and  Christian Moen